# Como suscribirse a SNS desde un pod

Tags: nodejs, aws, kubernetes, nestjs

Tengo un microservicio dentro de un pod el cual está usando el sdk de aws para suscribirse a un tópico de SNS. Mediante el sdk logro la solicitud de suscripción y este queda pendiente de confirmación. Pero el SNS al intentar confirmar el endpoint de mi microservicio da error de timeout.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Log de cloudwatch del SNS:

```
{
"notification": {
    "messageId": "8d9508c9-9bfa-4adf-a773-71a6a7abf11f",
    "topicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:999999999:SNS-BR-DEV-PU-QUEUE",
    "timestamp": "2022-08-16 21:19:48.2"
},
"delivery": {
    "deliveryId": "2ebc1878-fe3d-5bd7-bc54-430ef3163fe7",
    "destination": "http://id-load-balancer.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ms-sd10009-oi00003-dataparser/sns-listener",
    "providerResponse": "ConnectTimeoutException in HttpClient",
    "dwellTimeMs": 292336,
    "attempts": 4
},
"status": "FAILURE" 
}
```

Al parecer el error esta que el SNS no logra realizar la petición desde afuera hacia el pod pero el microservicio si logra salir al SNS por sdk.

Answer (score 0):

El problema resultaba ser en que el endpoint debe ser públicamente accesible para que SNS pueda realizar la confirmación, como expone el siguiente artículo:

https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-topic-https-endpoints-notification/

Por lo cual se pensó en dos alternativas

- Implementar una lambda para que ejecute la suscripción y
  confirmación, haciendo de intermediario entre el SNS y el microservicio.
- Crear un internet-facing load balancers y así llegar al pod que contiene el microservicio.

Comment: ¿Debe ser públicamente accesible? La pregunta no es trivial porque no sabemos si eso es seguro. No será que debes revisar los security groups, las reglas y demás en tus vpc?